# How to cut a plane at random points?

Tags: image, generative-art

I hope that someone can help me understand how to perform the following algorithm in *Mathematica*, I am taking as reference the next page [reference page](http://paulbourke.net/fractals/noise/) in your section planar version [image: algorithm desire], the problem is that I still have no idea how to start, I hope someone is So kind to help me. I have tried several hours to implement something but without success. thank you very much for your help

Comment: Show us what you have tried so far; it may be a good starting point for a solution.

Comment: Raise or lowered by how much?

Answer (score 6):

We can use [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/274728/380122) answer on math.SE to determine on which side of a line a point lies. Based on this formula, we have that the new gray level is given by

```
f[{{x1_, y1_}, {x2_, y2_}}][gl_, {x_, y_}] := gl + 0.1 Sign[(x - x1) (y2 - y1) - (y - y1) (x2 - x1)]
```

We can apply this to all pixels recursively in the following manner:

```
iterate[img_] := Module[{dimx, dimy, pts},
  {dimx, dimy} = ImageDimensions[img];
  pts = Transpose[{RandomInteger[dimx, 2], RandomInteger[dimy, 2]}];
  ImageApplyIndexed[f[pts], img]
  ]

img = ConstantImage[0.5, {300, 300}];
Nest[iterate, img, 50]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Below is another test run with more iterations, and I also changed the constant 0.1 in front of `Sign` to 0.02. This constant determines how much each side is raised or lowered, and it has a big influence on the visual effect.

```
Nest[iterate, img, 100]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

I'm not sure how to prove correctness for this algorithm, so if anyone spots an error please tell me.

Comment: Your `pts` array is {{x,x},{y,y}} rather than {{x,y},{x,y}} like `f` is expecting.  Maybe throw a `Transpose` in there so it will work when the image isn't square.

Comment: @wxffles Good catch, thank you.