# How to use Nest with the following function?

Tags: programming, function-construction

I would like to ask your help with this problem I have to use Nest.

Checking the code that shared @Sascha in this thread [Generate landscape by cutting a plane](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/136592/generate-landscape-by-cutting-a-plane-in-3d/136608?noredirect=1#comment368763_136608), I am trying to do in the pc the part that says **Advanced usage**, but the problem is that I do not know how to use `Nest` with the step function of that section, since you can not put

```
Nest[Step, RandomVariate[0, 0.02], 0, 1500]
```

because I am getting error, maybe someone from you can clarify me how to do the 1500 iterations that are mentioned in that thread.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Generate landscape by cutting a plane in 3d](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/136592/generate-landscape-by-cutting-a-plane-in-3d)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a big difference between the built-in function `Step` and Sascha's function `step`.

```
step[dist_][prev_] :=
  With[
     {stepsize := RandomVariate[dist],
      rand := RandomReal[{-1, 1}]},
    prev + stepsize Sign[rand x + rand y + rand]]

SeedRandom[9];
Plot3D[
  Evaluate @ Nest[step[NormalDistribution[0, 1]], 0, 1500], {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1},
  ColorFunction -> "GreenBrownTerrain",
  Boxed -> False,
  Exclusions -> None,
  BoundaryStyle -> None,
  Axes -> None,
  Mesh -> None]
```

[image: plot]

#### Edit

I have changed the plot options. The final effect is to give a more eroded look to the terrain, more Appalachians than Alps. It also plots much faster because exclusions are not being considered.

Comment: Thank you very much for your quick response, it is true that it is faster, but I really like the finished Sascha I mean the crumpled or embossed landscape, to achieve it I must take into account Exclusions?

Comment: @user1935664. Sasha did not reveal the details of how he plotted his landscape. I have not been able to find the options which reproduce the the look he gets. I believe he must have specified some options concerning exceptions, but don't know what they were.

Comment: I have been very clear the reason about the null information of Sascha for the construction of the landscape, thanks for the help of Nest